# Running bundle exec cucumber is fine, but just running cucumber doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm using cucumber 1.0 installed with cucumber-rails on Rails 3.  I'd like to use autotest, but it seems autotest invokes cucumber with just `cucumber` and not `bundle exec cucumber` .  `bundle exec cucumber` works fine for me, but when I run it with just `cucumber`, I get:

```
Using the default profile...
uninitialized constant Diff::ReadableDiffer (NameError)
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/test-unit-2.3.0/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:336:in `<module:Console>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/test-unit-2.3.0/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:17:in `<module:UI>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/test-unit-2.3.0/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:16:in `<module:Unit>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/test-unit-2.3.0/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:15:in `<module:Test>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/test-unit-2.3.0/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/redgreen-1.2.2/lib/redgreen.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/Users/Mike/Projects/exlab/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/Mike/Projects/exlab/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-rails-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `rescue in require'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/Mike/Projects/exlab/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:176:in `load_file'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:78:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `each'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `load_files!'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.0.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

Any clues?

Comment: For me, ``bundle exec cucumber`` works fine, but just ``cucumber`` throws: ``-bash: cucumber: command not found``. Maybe it depends on how you installed cucumber. My error results after ``gem install cucumber``. What about you?

Comment: these might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484378/rails-3-cucumber-problem-already-activated-builder-3-0-0-but-your-gemfile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484378/rails-3-cucumber-problem-already-activated-builder-3-0-0-but-your-gemfile

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with [TestUnit being replaced by MiniTest in Ruby1.9](http://jamesmead.org/blog/2009-02-02-test-unit-and-minitest-with-different-ruby-versions). You could solve it adding this to your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'test-unit', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```